# jquery ui dialog drop downs not working in IE 9 on IIS7 or .Net 4

Tags: jquery-ui, iis

I have a page that works fine on my local box running IIS 7.5 and Windows 7. I'm using VS 2013 for development, and have .Net 4.5.1 installed. I'm using jquery-2.0.3 and jquery-ui-1.10.3. They're both loaded on my web server and on my local machine. Unfortunately, my work is still using IE 9 for a browser. I have a jquery ui dialog with several form fields in it. Everything works fine on my local box. When I upload it to our web server, which is running IIS 7 and .Net 4 the dropdowns on this form don't work when clicking them. Using the tab key to switch fields on the form works, but not using the mouse or touchscreen. I can use dropdown and then can't use the mouse to select a value in a second dropdown. I've spent hours googling and on this site and am not seeing anything relevant.I have a feeling our it people will not want to upgrade the web server. Any suggestions? TIA.

```
$('#Pst').dialog({
autoOpen: false,
title: 'Add',
modal: true,
width: 800,
resizable: false,
cache: false,
buttons: {
  "Save": function () {
    $('#update-message').html('');
    $('#frm').submit();
  },
  "Cancel": function () {
    $(this).dialog("close");
  }
},
close: function () {
  $(this).dialog("close");
}
}).height("auto");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a hack that works, although makes the form jumpy and it won't submit for some reason. http://albert-mylearning.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-ui-dailog-ie-and-dropdownlist.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. It was because the jquery ui library was included twice on a page.

Comment: I thought I had answered this one, but you're right. There were two different version of jquery on the web server.